# php templating engine, preg_replace

Tags: php, preg-replace, pcre

Hey I'm trying to make a templating engine, but ran in to a problem with the if statement

```
$this->template = preg_replace('~@if\((.*?)\)~', '?php if($1): ?', $this->template);
    $this->template = preg_replace('~@elseif\((.*?)\)~', '<?php elseif($1): ?>', $this->template);
    $this->template = preg_replace('~@else~', '<?php else: ?>', $this->template);
    $this->template = preg_replace('~@endif~', '?php endif; ?', $this->template);
```

what happens is that if i try to replace a string, with other brackets in the string, preg_replace takes the first, and not the right on

example

```
@if(!isset($active)) Show @endif
```

becomes

```
<?php if(!isset($active): ?>) Show @endif
```

Comment: Matching pairs in a nested manner (here: `(` and `)`) cannot be expressed with regular languages that regular expressions belong to. You need at least a context-free language. However, [PCRE does support recursive patterns](http://php.net/regexp.reference.recursive).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To describe something enclosed between parenthesis with eventual nested parenthesis inside, the pattern is (example for the "if" pattern):

```
~@if\(([^()]*+(?:\((?-1)\)[^()]*)*+)\)~
```

`(?-1)` stands for the subpattern in the last opened capture group. Since it is in the capture group itself, you obtain a recursion. *(Note that you can also call the subpattern with the number of the capture group with `(?1)` and not in a relative way like in the example, but the relative way is more useful when a pattern contains several capture groups.)*

The pattern uses possessive quantifiers `*+` (that forbids backtracking) to fail faster when the string is not well formatted.

Comment: Oh, thank you very much, also makes more sense now :)

Comment: Next question will be: How can I ignore parentheses in strings?

Comment: @Gumbo: to do it, you must replace each `[^()]*+` with `[^()"']*+(?:(?:"[^"\\]*+(?s:\\.[^"\\]*)*+"|'[^'\\]*+(?s:\\.[^'\\]*)*+')[^()"']*)*+`